# import class file in Jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, obfuscation

I have several scripts written in Jruby that I would like to obfuscate by converting them to .class files. But I am running into an error when I tried to access the .class file using Jruby.

My file structure looks like this:

```
temp/action.rb
temp/src/Test2.rb

#temp/src/Test2.rb

class Test2
    def self.add(num1,num2)
        return num1 + num2
    end
end
```

I converted Test2.rb to .class files using

```
jrubyc Test2.rb
```

which produce the following .class files :

`Test2.class`

Now, I trying to access Test2 and its methods from another jruby file, `action.rb`

```
    #temp/action.rb

    require 'java'

    $CLASSPATH << "src"

    java_import 'Test2'

    t = Test2.new
    puts t.add(2,3)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'add' for <Java::Default::Test2:0x369f73a2>
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `def self.add` defines a "class" (singleton) method. You can use it with `puts Test2.add(2,3)`. Or you remove `self` in the definition and can use it as an instance method in `t = Test2.new; puts t.add(2,3)`.

Comment: @BernardK I have tried both methods, each resulting in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used JRuby for five years and discover strange things. Given the file `Test2.rb` :

```
class Test2
    def self.addc(num1, num2)
        num1 + num2
    end

    def self.xyz
        puts 'xyz'
    end

    def addi(num1, num2)
        num1 + num2
    end
end

puts Test2.addc(4,6)

t = Test2.new
puts t.addi(2, 3)
```

which I compile :

```
$ jrubyc Test2.rb 
$ jruby -J-cp .:/Users/b/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/jruby.jar use_t.rb 
in use_t.rb
NoMethodError: undefined method `addc' for Java::Default::Test2:Class
```

Then I read in Using Jruby (from Pragmatic Programmers, but no longer available) :

> If you pass the --java option to jrubyc, it will generate a .java file
>   instead of a .class file. You can then fall back on familiar Java
>   tools to finish the job.

```
$ jrubyc --java Test2.rb
$ javac -cp .:/Users/b/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/jruby.jar Test2.java 
Test2.java:16: error: unclosed string literal
        String source = new StringBuilder("class Test2
                                          ^
Test2.java:17: error: illegal character: '\'
\n" +
^
```

I open `Test2.java` and see :

```
public class Test2 extends RubyObject  {
    private static final Ruby __ruby__ = Ruby.getGlobalRuntime();
    private static final RubyClass __metaclass__;

    static {
        String source = new StringBuilder("class Test2
\n" +
            "    def self.addc(num1, num2)
\n" +
            "        num1 + num2
\n" +
            "    end
\n" +
...
```

I edit this file to "repair" it like so :

```
static {
    String source = new StringBuilder("class Test2\n" +
        "    def self.addc(num1, num2)\n" +
        "        num1 + num2\n" +
        "    end\n" +
        "    \n" +
        "    def self.xyz\n" +
        "        puts 'xyz'\n" +
        "    end\n" +
        "\n" +
...
```

Then recompile

```
$ javac -cp .:/Users/b/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/jruby.jar Test2.java
```

and, with file `use_t.rb` :

```
require 'java'

#$CLASSPATH << '.'
java_import 'Test2'

puts "in #{__FILE__}"

Test2.xyz

puts ::Test2.addc(8,9)

t = ::Test2.new
puts t.addi(2,3)
```

execute :

```
$ jruby -J-cp .:/Users/b/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/jruby.jar use_t.rb 
10
5
uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:93: warning: already initialized constant Test2
in use_t.rb
xyz
17
5
```

It works ! Strange detour.

It's not a problem of coercing parameters, because `xyz` alone :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `xyz' for Java::Default::Test2:Class
```

Then I try another version :

```
$ rvm install jruby
...
jruby-9.1.7.0 - #configure
jruby-9.1.7.0 - #download
...
jruby-9.1.7.0 - #generating default wrappers........
$ rvm use jruby
Using /Users/b/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0
```

Compile again :

```
$ jrubyc Test2.rb 
TypeError: failed to coerce org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter to org.jruby.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
  block in compile_files_with_options at /Users/b/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jruby/compiler.rb:189
```

Then I download the latest release (`jruby-complete-9.1.15.0.jar`) from [jruby.org](http://jruby.org) and, with this error, I find in a [forum](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2887) that somebody used the following command and try it :

```
$ java -cp .:/userdata/Sources/jruby-complete-9.1.15.0.jar org.jruby.Main ./use_t.rb  
10
5
uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:95: warning: already initialized constant Test2
in ./use_t.rb
xyz
17
5
```

It works, but don't ask why :(

Comment: this is an interesting work around. Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work when my files are packed inside a .JAR file. It works fine outside of the jar.